# FontForge Missing Curve Handles?

Tags: bezier, fontforge

I'm using FontForge v 20200314 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

I'm having an issue where curve points do not display handles. I have tried adding additional points to no avail. Some of my curve points do create handles and curve, but I can't discern a logic to it.

Granted, I've been using Adobe programs for 20 years, so I'm thinking I'm probably just having the wrong expectations of the tools. I attached a screen shot for reference. In it you can see that only some curve points have handles.

I have tried Point> Make Curve, but that causes the program to crash consistently. I have Show> Control Points Always selected.

Any advice is much appreciated.

[Can't embed images, but it's a screenshot of the curves expecting different than expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1bG6.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the point is a corner or tangent, the one or both of the handles may disappear, but occasionally curves don't have any either. You should be able to drag one of the adjacent lines to add a control point on that side if nothing is selected (once something is selected this behavior changes). You can also select the point, right-click, and select a different type (possible multiple times), but this will usually change the handles and shape quite a bit.